# C# Calling A Flash Variable From Another Form?

Tags: c#, variables, controls

I am in need of a bit of help searched around the internet for about 2 days
to try and figure out how i can call an AxShockwaveFlash Variable from a second form this is for a game trainer something simple just getting into C# so i thought id start with one of these however i love everything i make to have a nice look and as many options as i can add so for my first C# Trainer i added a MenuStrip that opens a second form(VariableMods.cs) it has a few radio buttons a text box 3 toggle switches and 2 buttons one for setting a variable to whatever is typed in the text box while checking which radio button is checked and a button to close the variable menu which is another thing i need a bit of help with

-How do i Close the Second Form but still keep my Toggles On?
-How do i Call A Variable From (Form1.cs) to Form2(VariableMods.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OCULAS
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //Show the Variable ModMenu
    private void openVariableModsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VariableMods VarMenu = new VariableMods(this);
        VarMenu.Show();
    }
    //Show About Program Box
    private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InfoBox1 AboutBoxx = new InfoBox1();
        AboutBoxx.Show();
    }
    //Close the Program
    private void closeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

}
```

}

That is my Form1 Code Have Not Put anything into it about the ShockwaveFlash yet

And
here is Form2(VariableMods)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OCULAS
{
public partial class VariableMods : Form
{
    Form1 originalForm; //Using "OriginalForm" To Call "Form1"

    public VariableMods(Form1 IncomingForm)
    {
        originalForm = IncomingForm; //originalForm(Form1) is the form to be called
        InitializeComponent();
        BoxHeadVariables utf = new BoxHeadVariables();

    }



    private void ambiance_Button_21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void ambiance_Button_11_Click(Form1 incomingForm, object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ambiance_RadioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Damage Mod Is Active");
        }
        if (ambiance_RadioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Speed Mod Is Active");
        }
        if (ambiance_RadioButton3.Checked == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Range Mod Is Active");
        }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you to take a look on [MVP (Model View Presenter)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317693/what-is-model-view-presenter) this should help you with communication between forms.

Comment: Thanks ill give it a look